# GPIO02 and GPIO05 not working on i.MX7D android things

Tags: android, android-things

I am trying to write out to GPI pins on the ANDROID THINGS i.MX7D.  GPIO6  pins seem to work fine but writing out to GPIO5 or GPIO2 does not.

I have leds connected to the pins and have tried using an android app and the pio cli tool.  Same results.

Am I not enabling those GPIOs someplace?  Are they different than GPIO6?

Comment: Are you using [the default pinout](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d#io-pinout) or a custom one?

Comment: I'm quite sure I've used at least the ones of GPIO02 several times, but do doggie check you're not putting an uppercase o instead of a zero and the other way around 0 and O are very similar on the printouts and I made that mistake myself

Comment: I am using default pinout.  I dbl checked the text - verified no 0 when when should be O.

Comment: I am using the default pinout - how can I change it if it might make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you can use [PIO CLI tool](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/pio-cli.html) to list names of available pins:

```
$ pio list
```

and to set/reset `GPIO02` and `GPIO05` pins from your PC with command:

```
$ pio gpio GPIO2_IO03 write 1
```

or

```
$ pio gpio GPIO2_IO03 write 0
```

bypassing your application. If the LEDs are not controlled using the PIO CLI tool, the problem is the hardware (possibly the connections).

Check GPIO names [here](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d#io-pinout), you should use full `GPIO2_IO03`name instead of only `GPIO2`.

Also make sure that no other applications are using the GPIO lines (take a look at [that](https://gist.github.com/blundell/7c0c3bb17898b28fe8122b0dc230af50) script of [Blundell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413127/blundell)).

Comment: Thanks for the script - I'll do that.  I used the PIO CLI Tool just as you described on multiple devices.  Same issue. GPIO6_IOXX Pins work fine.  But the others don't.  Just strange.

Comment: Try reflash Android Things image.

Comment: I reflashed to ensure all GPIO pins were enabled.  I am getting the same result.  I connected a voltmeter to measure the change in voltage when I use the PIO CLI Tool to change state.  The voltage DOES change (0V for write 0, and 3.3V for write 1).  However the LED is actually very DIM.  I missed this before.  Anyone know what the circuit on the dev board is configured as (I configured all pins the same in the console when I created the image - GPIOx_IOxx, 100k pull-down.).  Maybe the dev board is wired differently?

Comment: So, it's the hardware issue. LEDs should not be powered from GPIO pin. They are should be powered from +3.3V or +5V pin via 0.5KOhm resistor (like in [this tutorial](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/tutorial-flashing-led-using-gpio-output)) and GPIO pin should connect it to the Ground pin.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.  The GPIO6 bus is also the CAN bus driver on the chip. It's natively 3.3V and is run directly to the expansion header on the breakout board. The other GPIO busses are all 1.8V.  Connecting the pin using as a SINK (~1K pull-up resistor to 3.3V, on when LOW) works.